# How do I use a variable as a field name in a Mongo query in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How would I go about using a variable as a field name in a Mongo query in a Meteor application.

Here is an example...

This runs a find on my request controllers collection after capitalizing the collection name for the parent id of a child.  The child is the **users** field.

```
window[Meteor.request.controller.capitalise()]["find"]({ _id: Session.get('parent_id'), users: params.child }).count()
```

As you can see my controller is a variable name for the collection item which allows me to have a single line of code for finding children of controller/collections but I need to be able to set the child field name to a variable.  In the above example that would be **users** but I want it to be a variable name.

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
window[Meteor.request.controller.capitalise()]["find"]({ _id: Session.get('parent_id'), [Session.get('child_collection_name').decapitalise()]: params.child }).count()
```

where

```
Session.get('child_collection_name').decapitalise()
```

returns **users**

Any ideas?  If I can figure out how to use a variable name in a mongo query in meteor it would reduce my code footprint significantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The query is just a JavaScript object, so you can build it step by step:

```
var query = { _id: Session.get('parent_id') };
var myCustomField = Session.get('child_collection_name').decapitalise();
var myCustomValue = params.child;
query[myCustomField] = myCustomValue;
var count = SomeCollection.find(query).count();
```

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Yeah works great!  I have even been able to figure out how to use it for $pull.  Can't get it to work for $addToSet yet though.  This has reduced my code footprint size by about 80%!