# Dynamically create Meteor.js MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For some reason I'm having a hard time getting this to work.  I have a Mongo collection called 'cats', and another called 'rows'.  The `cat` field in 'cats' is `currentCat`.  Then I want to be able to update a document in 'rows' by referring to a preexisting document with an `_id`.  No problems there.  But for every `currentCat`, I want to add an  element to the 'rows' document with `currentCat` as the field and something else as the value (`currentPer`).  I came up with this:

```
var cats = Cats.find({owner: Meteor.userId()}, {fields: {cat: 1, per: 1}});

cats.forEach(function(cats) { //Inserts the rest of the row
  var currentCat = cats['cat'];
  var currentPer = cats['per'];
  var currentAmount = Math.round(amount*currentPer*100)/100;

  Rows.update(
    { _id: row },
    { $push: { currentCat: currentAmount } }
  );
});
```

(`row` is the id of the document I want modified)

Of course, it doesn't work as expected and just inserts `...{currentCat: 57}` instead of the value of the variable `currentCat`.  Next, I tried creating a query object (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023946/2129808)):

`var query = ({ _id: row }, { $push: { currentCat: currentAmount } })`

That also failed, but this time with a wonderfully descriptive error message:

`Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.`

Any help would be appreciated, as I've spent hours and countless Google searches on this (although the answer is probably obvious and I just can't see it - I'm still trying to get used to Meteor after PHP).

**EDIT**: I want the finished document to look something like this:

```
 { "_id" : "PshEYKebccw7eYaTo", 
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-26T00:52:51.840Z"),
   "cat1" : 312,
   "cat2" : 564,
   "owner" : "GiWCb8jXbPfzyc5ZF",
   "text" : "asdf" 
}
```

Comment: can you show the json you are expecting to get?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Added an example to it.

Comment: What do you want a Row document to look like?  Based on your code, I'm expecting something like `{_id: 123, currentCat: [5.25, 6.75, 1.55, 2.78]}`

Comment: @Colllin Please see my example.  I want to have a field and value pair for each `cat`.

Comment: Ok, so basically you missed the point of the query object in that other answer.  In Javascript, `{ currentCat: currentAmount }` becomes `{ 'currentCat': 312 }` because the key must be a literal key.  You can't use a variable as the key name.  In order to do that, you must build up the object as in my answer below.  By using the square bracket notation, you can set a dynamic key on the object, and then send that object into the query.  `catData[currentCat]` first interprets the `currentCat` variable to be `'cat1'`, and then accesses that key, as if you had done `catData['cat1']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$push` is only for operating on arrays.  Based on your example of a Row document, you don't really want an array operation here.

Try just setting fields on the Row document for each new cat value.

```
  var catData = {};
  catData[currentCat] = currentAmount;
  // As an example, catData now looks like {'cat1': 312}

  Rows.update(
    { _id: row },
    { $set: catData }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now works perfectly.  I ended up declaring `catData` before the `forEach` and put `Rows.update()` after.  Also, as a bonus, I now only access the database once instead of multiple times for each `cat`.