# Iterating through an array with Spacebars

Tags: meteor, spacebars

This is somewhat of a part 2 to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27140053/2129808).  Thanks to some helpful folks, I now have a document that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "dndsZhRgbPK24n5LD", "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-26T16:28:02.655Z"), "data" : { "cat1" : 493.6, "cat2" : 740.4 }, "owner" : "GiWCb8jXbPfzyc5ZF", "text" : "asdf" }
```

Specifically, I want to extract the value from each property of `data` in Spacebars and iterate over it to create a table - and I know the number of fields in object `data` but the number can vary.  Yes, I know this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21815713/2129808) but nobody has seemed to be able to give a satisfactory answer that works.  But as a final result I would like to display the whole document in a row, like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>493.6</td>
    <td>740.4</td>
    <td>asdf</td>
</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's complete working example:

```js
Cats = new Mongo.Collection(null);

Meteor.startup(function() {
  Cats.insert({
    data: {
      cat1: 100,
      cat2: 200
    },
    text: 'cat1'
  });

  Cats.insert({
    data: {
      cat1: 300,
      cat2: 400,
      cat3: 500
    },
    text: 'cat2'
  });
});

Template.cats.helpers({
  cats: function() {
    return Cats.find();
  },

  // Returns an array containg numbers from a cat's data values AND the cat's
  // text. For example if the current cat (this) was:
  // {text: 'meow', data: {cat1: 100, cat2: 300}}, columns should return:
  // [100, 200, 'meow'].
  columns: function() {
    // The current context (this) is a cat document. First we'll extract an
    // array of numbers from this.data using underscore's values function:
    var result = _.values(this.data);

    // result should now look like [100, 200] (using the example above). Next we
    // will append this.text to the end of the result:
    result.push(this.text);

    // Return the result - it shold now look like: [100, 200, 'meow'].
    return result;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  {{> cats}}
</body>

<template name='cats'>
  <table>
    {{#each cats}}
      <tr>
        {{#each columns}}
          <td>{{this}}</td>
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>
```

Comment: Please see my updated question.  The problem is that I not only want to display the `data` object, but also the rest of the document.

Comment: I updated the answer with a tested solution. Is that what you are looking for? I'm unclear from the question if each document has the same structure or if the number of fields varies.

Comment: The number of fields in `data` can vary.  That combined with displaying the rest of the document makes a knot.

Comment: Okay - try the updated version. There are a million different ways to write the `columns` helper but the overall structure should help you implement a solution.

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly now.  I didn't know you could reference `this` in a helper function.

Comment: Do you have a question about the answer? If so, I'm happy to help.

Comment: your `columns` template helper is not straightforward; it's unclear whether youre using Meteor conventions or javascript methods.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with fully commented code for `columns`. Let me know if that helps or if you need additional clarification.